# Prove or disprove $\int^{\infty}_{0}(\prod^{n}_{r=1}\cos\frac{x}{r})\frac{\sin(4x)}{x}dx=\frac{\pi}{2}$

Tags: integration

$$\int^{\infty}_{0}(\prod^{n}_{r=1}\cos\frac{x}{r})\frac{\sin(4x)}{x}dx=\frac{\pi}{2}$$
I highly suspect that the relation is true. How would I go about proving this? I thought it would be induction related but I cannot get anywhere with it as it quickly leads (through parts) to integrating $\frac{\sin x}{x}$

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Explain why $\int_0^\infty\frac{\sin{4x}}{x}\prod\limits_{k=1}^n \cos\left(\frac{x}{k}\right) dx\approx\frac{\pi}{2}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2108578/explain-why-int-0-infty-frac-sin4xx-prod-limits-k-1n-cos-left-frac) – According to that Q&A, your conjecture is true for $n \le 30$, but wrong for $n \ge 31$.

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1022868/42969. – Both found with [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Cint%5E%7B%5Cinfty%7D_%7B0%7D(%5Cprod%5E%7Bn%7D_%7Br%3D1%7D%5Ccos%5Cfrac%7Bx%7D%7Br%7D)%5Cfrac%7B%5Csin(4x)%7D%7Bx%7Ddx%3D%5Cfrac%7B%5Cpi%7D%7B2%7D%24&p=1)